# Computing the longest common subsequence of two lists in Scheme in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, scheme, racket

So I need to calculate the longest common subsequence of two lists, but it needs to be in polynomial time. The only problem i'm having is that I'm not allowed to use "!" at all. This means that I can't change the value of a vetcor or list using set!. I can't find a polynomial algorithm that doesn't require a 2d list or array of some sort. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `set!` (or any other mutating operation) to use 2d lists or vectors.

You can use the standard dynamic programming algorithm with a 2d vector, but instead of changing the vector to insert the value you calculated for a given cell, you use `build-vector` to create a new vector which is the same as the old one, except you changed the value at the given position.

This is highly inefficient, but still polynomial, and I don't think it's possible to do this really efficiently without laziness or mutation.

Edit: Using `build-vector` to do this, would look something like this:

```
(build-vector n (lambda (i)
  (build-vector n (lambda (j)
    (if (and (= i x) (= j y))
        new-value
        (vector-ref (vector-ref old-vector i) j))))))
```

Where `old-vector` is the `n*n` vector you want to copy, and you want to replace the value at position `x,y` with the value `new-value`. (Note: Using a function like this is almost always a mistake in real life because, as I said, this is quite inefficient).

Comment: Could you explain how I could use build-vector? I'm not sure how could create a copy using this.

Comment: Thanks alot! I really appreciate it. Would "n" be the new vector created, or do I have to put in a define before all this? (Sorry, I'm very new to scheme)

Comment: @john: No, `n` is just supposed to be the size of the vector. The newly created vector will be the return value of the expression. So yes, you need to put a `define` or `let` in front of that or put it directly as an argument to your recursive function call.

Comment: Thanks alot! You've been a life saver

Comment: build-vector doens't seem to work in the version of scheme I need to use. Any alternative ideas?